# Node.js - RESTful does not show any results

Tags: node.js

this might be a very simple question, I, however, still don't understand why I can't get any results from my codes. I've been coding in Node.js by using Nodepad++ editor. I think every parts of my code has zero errors, why I can't see any results on the webpage(localhost)?
Or is there something I didn't include?

Thank you for your time

[image: server.js]

[image: movies.js]

[image: Result]

[image: mongoDB]

[image: Cmd]

Comment: p.s. I corrected 'bodyParser.urlencoded({extened:false})' to 'bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false})' that 'd' was taken off but the result is still the same

Comment: compare console value and json value after call api